# FOR /f in DOS alternative

Tags: batch-file, dos

As it appears there is no version of DOS (6.22 to WinME "DOS") or FreeDOS that allows you to take part of a text file and make it a variable, I'm going to just keep collecting the data I get in DOS mode into one very large file but I can't think of a way to get each `asset` and `UUID` and add them together in a third file...  Here is what I get at the moment:

SMBIOS.TXT

```
~~~~~~~(usually 27 lines of stuff I don't need)~~~~~~~
Asset Number: ABC12345
~~~~~~~(usually 37 lines of stuff I don't need)~~~~~~~
UUID: ABCDEF12345678901234567890
~~~~~~~(usually 4 lines of stuff I don't need, complicated by a # symbol in there too)~~~~~~~
^Repeated many times
```

I need to add both the Asset Number and the `UUID` together in a CSV format so I was previously hoping (before I exhausted all attempts at doing `for /F` in DOS) just echoing the two variables I was creating as follows:

`ECHO !Asset!,!UUID!>>Results.CSV`

Which again works in Windows command prompt just not DOS, the script I'm using however only gets the first variable of each so I need to do them in order and keep repeating through the file in the manner?

Alternatively is there any other way I could use DOS to get the info I need out of the two text files on the fly?  It's all running from a USB stick so I don't have any size constraints at least.

Aaron

Comment: Have you considered finding (and including) some version of [sed](http://www.pement.org/sed/) for dos?

Comment: A true DOS (not Windows) machine, with support for USB !? That surprises me. Are you really in a position that you cannot use a Windows batch file with support for FOR /F ?

Comment: You could try a different command interpreter like 4DOS, or, alternately, write your own program.  You could use QBASIC if you're really in the mood for nostalgia.

Comment: I too would go for QBasic. It has some nice file and string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get it done with the DOS command line text stream editor EDLIN. 
I am assuming this has to be done in DOS and Windows is not an option.
PDGREPPE is an MS DOS command line GREP search and replace utility.
Maybe you can find a DOS Text Editor with Macros
Lotus 123?
DBase?
Write an app in DOS BASIC.