# How do I print a specified line of a text file without using 'FOR /F'?

Tags: dos

I would like to be able to print a specified line of a text file like this:

```
C:\>type test.txt
foo
bar
foo
bar
C:\>printline test.txt 2
bar
```

However, 'for /f' cannot be used as it is not available in FreeDOS, which I'm designing my program for use with.

What can I do instead? I had looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895272/for-f-in-dos-alternative) and it didn't help me.

Comment: Does standard `for` exist in FreeDOS? and what about `for /L`? Does FreeDOS support [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)?

Comment: I don't understand why you would design a program to work with an OS, if you don't know, _or don't reveal_, which commands are available to it!

Comment: Standard     for exists for both MS-DOS and FreeDOS. However, FreeDOS does not support any setlocal commands (like delayed expansion), but it does support redirection.

Comment: @aschipfl - The DOS and FreeDOS versions of `for` have no flags at all.

Comment: What about `set`, does it have any flags in FreeDOS?

Comment: set has /c, /p, /e, /u, and /?. /p works the same way as Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You write a program that allows you to do so. `for /f` is not available in FreeDOS as it was not available in DOS' `command.com`, since FreeDOS aims to be compatible to MS-DOS.

The other option is that you don't do this at all.

Comment: I can also use MS-DOS or Windows 9x command prompt, but no NT or Linux/Unix, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the command line of Microsoft LogParser?

Comment: I don't think LogParser can be used as I'm working with FreeDOS and MS-DOS, and LogParser is for Server 2003. I cannot use Windows NT as this must be bootable from a floppy disk if needed.